# How to add a button to the inline "Message" ribbon in outlook?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, ribbonx

I've successfully added a new button to the Message ribbon in Outlook for sending new messages or when using the pop out feature to reply to messages by creating a custom ribbon/button in C# in VS but can not for the life of me figure out how to get that same button on the Message ribbon that appears when replying to a message inline. Is there a particular ribbon control id I need to use? I have been unable to find any useful information about it online anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TabComposeTools` idMso value for the `tabSet` attribute and the `TabMessage` value for the `IdMso` property of the tab attribute. For example, you can use the following markup:

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <contextualTabs>
        <tabSet idMso="TabComposeTools">
            <tab idMso="TabMessage">

            // your controls go there

            </tab>
        </tabSet>
    </contextualTabs>
</ribbon>
```

See [Contextual tab for the Outlook inline response in Explorer windows.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b9a4802-ba51-4353-9bab-8383346767ba/contextual-tab-for-the-outlook-inline-response-in-explorer-windows?forum=vsto#:%7E:text=The%20inline%20response%20feature%20was%20introduced%20with%20Outlook,for%20the%20IdMso%20property%20of%20the%20tab%20attribute.) for more information.